# Is there a way to have modular parameter for PriorityQueue<modular>

Tags: java

Currently creating a code that uses 2 type of priority queues as separate methods, code is similar between the methods, trying to modulize them to become one single method, but the parameter is different in the type of priority queues

I am currently running eclipse, tried to ad if statement if 1 worked over the other. Problem is that the code requires an instantiation of the queue

```
public void function (String modular){

    if (modular == "A"){
        PriorityQueue<A> queue = new PriorityQueue<A>();
    }
    if (modular == "B"){
        PriorityQueue<B> queue = new PriorityQueue<B>();
    }

    queue.add(parameter,parameter)
}
```

Comment: We need some more context.

Comment: I already wrote the 2 classes A and B, and those classes are the parameters inside the priority queue. The problem that i am having is that i am running 2 different methods that use the same type of code, the main difference is that it depends on where i want to add the information to using either code A or code B. For further context, class A and B are 2 different type of vertices that i am trying to use. Trying to create a graph with vertices

Comment: So make the method generic on A or B, instead of passing a string parameter. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: Do class A and class B extend/implement a common super class/interface?

Comment: OP might not be familiar with the concept of generic methods, not many people are when they first got started

Comment: @user207421 Java does not support *union* (ie “or”) generic bounds, only *intersection* (ie “and”), so what you believe to be “obvious” is in fact impossible.

Comment: @Bohemian I failed to express myself clearly. I meant for him to do that at the call site, but actually as he also apparently has parameters of the type, all he needs is `public <T> void function(T parameter1, T parameter2)`, and, inside, `new PriorityQueue<T>()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [generic methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) to deal with that, example:

```
public <T> void function(PriorityQueue<T> queue){
    queue.add(whatever);
}
```

---

If your 2 (or more) types of classes extend the same parent class, you can use something like this:

```
public <T extends YOUR_PARENT_CLASS_NAME> void function(PriorityQueue<T> queue){
    queue.add(whatever);
}
```

To restrict what gets passed into the method.

Comment: Although if `queue.add()` is all that's in the method, there is no actual reason for this method to exist at all. The caller can call `queue.add()` himself instead.

Comment: yeah I guess, but there's probably more stuff in OP's code, otherwise, there's no reason to modulize that one line of code.

Comment: This won't compile. You're don't know `whatever` is a `T`.

Comment: Since I don't know what OP is going to do inside the function, I just added that `whatever` as a example, in actual code, you can definitely check for this kind of things. The point is you can use generic methods

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: In general? Nothing. But they won't work here, as I explained.